# Threshold and pinch-off voltages for N-channel depletion MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am confused about the MOSFET parameters. Consider a depletion N-channel MOSFET.  Suppose the gate-source (Vgs) threshold is Vth = -2V, in its off position. Suppose we have not reached the threshold and we are at Vgs = -1 V. This means that the MOSFET will conduct when a voltage Vds is applied (let Vds = +3 V to drain). There also exists the pinch-off voltage Vp beyond which saturation occurs.

Actual datasheets seem to suggest that Vth and Vp are independent of each other, yet I have seen statements such as Vds > Vgs - Vth. I am not sure if Vp = Vgs - Vth, as some discussions seem to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threshold voltage is the gate-source voltage \$V_{GS}=V_{Th}\$ at which drain-source charge flow begins.

The pinch-off voltage is a drain-source voltage \$V_{DS}=V_{PO}\$ at which saturation occurs. Definitely independent from \$V_{Th}\$.

(updated)
However, the pinch-off voltage is dependent on \$V_{GS}>V_{Th}\$ as shown in the image clipped  from [Dr. Bakr's lecture notes](https://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/faculty/bakr/ece2ei4/Lecture15_Web.pdf) below.
[image: Clip from Dr. Bakr lecture notes]

Comment: It is stated that the pinch-off locus constitutes Vgs-Vth, but I am not convinced it is actually true.

Comment: Let me give you an actual example.  Suppose I pass Vgs=-1V to the gate (let Vth=-3.5V).  Would that mean that if I use Vds=4V (positive on the drain), I would in effect be supplying -5V to the gate?

Comment: @Roger: Not at all. The voltage \$V_{DS}\$ has no effect on \$V_{GS}\$. All \$V_{GS}\$ does is modulate the channel resistance. There is no \$V_{DS}\$ unless there is drain current or a supply voltage

Comment: If I keep Vgs to 0V and apply a positive voltage to the drain, will saturation occur at when Vds reaches -Vth ?  If Vth is -3.5V, then would applying Vds at 3.5 give saturation?

Comment: @Roger: To both your comment questions, you are correct. See my updates and view the link.

Comment: Fantastic.  Then I understand things well enough.