# JFET Pinch-off voltage or threshold voltage

Tags: jfet, saturation

the operating condition of JFET in saturation is stated below from [this website](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-5/simulating-jfet-circuits-using-ltspice/).

[image]

Vp stands for pinch-off voltage in the article.

But after reading [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/643566/threshold-and-pinch-off-voltages-for-n-channel-depletion-mosfet) shouldn't Vp change to Vthreshold in Vds condition?
[image]

or like this, since Vp = Vgs - Vthreshold
[image]
Vthreshold is the voltage that JFET starts conducting current.

Am I correct?

Comment: I would be tempted to advise you to study a good book on semiconductors, one of the best known of which is - Physics of Semiconductor Devices - by S. M. SZE and similar.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'll look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This graph](https://medium.com/@bhimsenbgs2000/jfet-and-its-working-75bb5d625e0) shows where the saturation region is for an N-channel JFET: -

[image]

\$V_P\$ is the vertical dotted line representing the pinch-off voltage when \$V_{GS} = 0\text{ volts}\$. To the right of \$V_P\$ the device is deemed to be in the saturation region. If you choose a more negative value of \$V_{GS}\$ the pinch-off point reduces and follows the locus indicated.

The 2nd link in your question is not for a JFET; it's for a depletion mode MOSFET.

> *Vthreshold is the voltage that JFET starts conducting current.*

No, the JFET (N-channel) will conduct current when \$V_{GS}\$ is 0 volts and will only stop taking current when \$V_{GS}\$ becomes significantly negative in value.

Comment: So, could I understand it as there's no "threshold voltage" parameter in JFET device?

Comment: @JackHuang I never regard a JFET as having a threshold voltage (if that helps).